# How to we find a Tight Big O expression

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

```
for(i: 1 to n^2)
   x = x + 1;
return x + 1;
```

N is the number of inputs. N>1 and tends to infinity
I understand that the worst (and the best) case running time is `n^2 + 1`. Hence, it'll be `O(n^2)`. However, how do I find if it is a tight, big O expression? How do we find a tight big O expression? What is that?

Comment: Please, can you give us more info about n ?

Comment: The code mentioned could be considered a function. My question is what is tight, big oh expression? and how to we find it for this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let your function be f(n)

You already worked out that the best case is n^2 (ommit +1 since constants indepently from the input are ignored).

More formally: Ω(n^2) 
--> means you can find a function u(n) and a constant k such that k * u(n) <= f(n) in terms of complexity.

As you said the worst case is n^2 too.
Again formally: O(n^2)
--> means you can find a function v(n) and a constant k such that k * v(n) >= f(n) in terms of complexity.

Since Ω and O are sets of functions Theta is defined as the intersection of Ω and O. "Theta is upper and lower bound."

The intersection is n^2 --> Theta (n^2)

In an descriptive manner:

f(n) grows not much faster (or equal) than u(n).
f(n) grows not much faster (or equal) than v(n).
--> f(n) grows exactly like n^2

Keep in mind that mor often Ω and O are sets of different classes of functions.

E.g. Ω(log n)(searching in a tree) and O(n) (searching in a String) When dealing with such a case you are unable to specify an exact Theta value.